# Is there a c# equivalent of Java ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: c#, java

I need a dictionary/hashmap in c# that allow you to do the following

1. put values and iterate at the same time without a lock
2. lock only put. get are not locked and you may get many times concurrently

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/420860/equivalent-of-javas-concurrenthashmap-in-c

Comment: @Jairo: That is indeed a duplicate *question*, but its answers are pretty much obsolete now that there's a `ConcurrentDictionary<K,V>` class available in the BCL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Equivalent of java's ConcurrentHashMap in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420860/equivalent-of-javas-concurrenthashmap-in-c)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at the ConcurrentDictionary here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx. This should do what you're looking for. Keep in mind, it's .Net 4 only.

Answer (score 4):

check out the System.Collections.Concurrent - Namespace! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.aspx

Answer (score 4):

That sounds like [`ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx) to me, available in .NET 4.0 *or* .NET 3.5 if you've installed [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896).

Answer (score 0):

You could also write your own class by using the [`ReaderWriterLockSlim Class`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx).

Otherwise simply take a look into the [`System.Collections.Concurrent Namespace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.aspx).